# calculating prices in the load_boston dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

i am new to machine learning and need to build a house price prediction model for my project anyone who can help or guide me through i have no experience at all and i am just reading things online that seem to be way beyond my understanding

i am using the tutorial from this https://www.ritchieng.com/machine-learning-project-boston-home-prices/ but i get a very different value for prices

```
# Importing the libraries necessary for this project
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

# Loading the datasets for prediction
boston = load_boston()
prices = boston.target

boston_frame= pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
boston_frame['MEDV'] = prices
boston_frame.describe()

# Calculating the minimum, maximum, mean, median and standard deviation of 'MEDV'(i.e prices) in boston
minimum_price = prices.min()
maximum_price = np.max(prices)
mean_price = np.mean(prices)
median_price = np.median(prices)
std_price = np.std(prices)


# Show the calculated statistics
print("Statistics for Boston housing dataset:\n")
print(f"Minimum price: ${(minimum_price):.2f}")
print(f"Maximum price: ${(maximum_price):.2f}")
print(f"Mean price: ${(mean_price):.2f}")
print(f"Median price: ${(median_price):.2f}")
print(f"Standard Deviation of price: ${(std_price):.2f}")
```

below is my output which is far from what is in the tutorial and doesn't make sense how a house will be $5

```
Statistics for Boston housing dataset:

Minimum price: $5.00
Maximum price: $50.00
Mean price: $22.53
Median price: $21.20
Standard Deviation of price: $9.19
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the right result, it is in thousands of dollars.

Check the details of the boston dataset by adding a following code to read the description of the attributes in the dataset. The prices are in 1000 of dollars. So minimum price of $5 is actually $5000.

```
print (boston['DESCR'])
```

results:
:Attribute Information (in order):
- CRIM     per capita crime rate by town
- ZN       proportion of residential land zoned for lots over 25,000 sq.ft.
- INDUS    proportion of non-retail business acres per town
- CHAS     Charles River dummy variable (= 1 if tract bounds river; 0 otherwise)
- NOX      nitric oxides concentration (parts per 10 million)
- RM       average number of rooms per dwelling
- AGE      proportion of owner-occupied units built prior to 1940
- DIS      weighted distances to five Boston employment centres
- RAD      index of accessibility to radial highways
- TAX      full-value property-tax rate per $10,000
- PTRATIO  pupil-teacher ratio by town
- B        1000(Bk - 0.63)^2 where Bk is the proportion of blacks by town
- LSTAT    % lower status of the population
- MEDV     Median value of owner-occupied homes in $1000's

Comment: thank you so much...
please can you mail me so you can continue to help me through... plus is it okay if i multiply it by 1000 before displaying it

`print(f"Minimum price: ${(minimum_price*1000):.2f}")`

Comment: it depends on how you present the final outcome. for carrying out your regression and prediction, you might need to scale the data if the histogram shows that the data is skewed.

Comment: that sounds advanced to me but i will keep reading up...@Praks can i have your mail so we can communicate directly mine is femii.femiii@gmail.com